# Android Alarm reset after reboot not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, android-bootstrap

I have one class called **StopAlarmReceiver** and another **BootHandler**.

The **BootHandler** resets the alarm after reboot, which was set before the boot. My problem is that the **BootHandler** sets the **alarm but not getting fired**.

Entries in Manifest file.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.sign.android.myscheduler.app.StopAlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.sign.android.myscheduler.app.BootHandler"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Code in BootHandler.**

```
AlarmManager mgr= (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, StopAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, i, 0);

long time = sharedPreferences.getLong("Old_time", 0);
Log.e(TAG, "New time: " +new Date(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + time));

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + time, 5000, pi);
```

Comment: Do you hold the `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission? Have you run an activity in this app?

Comment: Yes I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> permission. User can set an Alarm by login into the App Activity. Then he close the app.

Answer (score 1):

**manifest**
   just write two receivers 1 for alarm and 1 for handle the boot

```
  <receiver
        android:name="packagename.AlarmReceiver"

        >

    </receiver>

    <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->
     <receiver android:name="com.avion.contact_app.DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

add following permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

In DeviceBootReceiver class check the intent action first

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "DefaultReminder", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))

    {
//do whatever you want after reboot or fire alarm again
}
}
```